# convert request from python to node js

Tags: python, node.js, request

I have a python request that works on the API I am trying to use.
I try to convert it in Node js but I can't manage to get the request executed.

python request:

```
import requests
url = 'https://simplivity@xxxx/api/'

hms_username = 'xxxx'
hms_password = 'xxxx'

response = requests.post(url+'oauth/token', auth=('simplivity', ''), verify=False, data={
  'grant_type':'password',
  'username':hms_username,
  'password':hms_password})
print(response.json())
```

Node JS request:

```
var https = require("https");

var options = {
    host: "simplivity@xxxx",
    path: "/api/oauth/token",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    res.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

const data = JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: 'password',
    'username': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxxx'
})

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

I don't understand what I did wrong between both of them.

I didn't pass the auth='simplivity' in the node js because I don't know where to put it.

Here are the outputs:

python:

```
tWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
{'access_token': 'xxxx', 'token_type': 'bearer', 'expires_in': 86399, 'scope': 'read write', 'updated_at': 1560771243707}
```

node js:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL simplivity@xxx simplivity@xxx:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

thank you

Comment: I recommend a higher level library like Superagent or Axios, They'll do the JSON encoding for you, and return promises, so you can do `var response = await superagent.post()` similar to what you're doing in Python

Comment: I'll check this out asap